# How can get Bitcoin client API account(<account>) name

Tags: api, bitcoin-core-accounts

I have setup the BIK_php API of  http://bitcoindevkit.com/  in PHP.
Now, I am able to connect and generate new addresses, but when I am going to call some functions like getaddressesbyaccount, sendfrom etc as given in Bitcoin API call list at https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_Calls_list , these functions requires "account" parameter as , but I could not understand where from I can get the account value?
So, Please let me know what will be the value of , and how can I get the   value from?

Comment: Does BIK_api (I don't know it) even use the accounts feature of bitcoind?

Comment: Thanks to comment! Is the Bitcoin Address Label is known as account name here? If we use External Bitcoin address then How can get the account name?

Comment: Addresses are not accounts. Accounts is for when for example you want to implement several users' wallets shared in one real wallet. They're just virtual balances, and have nothing to do with coin selection. There are few use cases for it, and few systems use it.

Comment: Thanks! Yes addresses are not accounts but when I call getaccount(<bitcoinaddress>) of BIK_api API by passing bitcoinaddress then it returns bitcoinaddress Label. So, I just want to confirm that the bitcoinaddress Label is the account name?

Comment: If a receive address R has label L, then payments sent to R will credit the account with label L. So yes, they coincide, but are not the same thing.

Comment: Ok, But if not same thing then what is the account name? and  in your case if we run getaccount(R) then it will return account L, so very confuse here between Label and Account?

Answer (score 1):

From the API page that you linked:

`getaccount <bitcoinaddress>` Returns the account associated with the given address.